# How can I solve $2^\gamma(2^\beta(2^\alpha - 1)-3)-9 = 0 (mod 27)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve $2^\gamma(2^\beta(2^\alpha - 1)-3)-9 = 0 (mod 27)$?

Should I solve it searching exhaustively for the solutions? Or is there a smartest way to do that?
Otherwise, is there any software that can help me to deal with this kind of equations?

Comment: By Euler's theorem, $2^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod {27}$, so it suffices to search for $0$ to $18$. I think it is not hard to make a simple program for this, 64bit integer will be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote a simple program that "brute force" the solutions in the range 0-18 and found them, but I am trying to find a smartest way to find them, without bruteforcing.

Comment: @didgogns _10bit_ integer (if there were such a variety) would be enough, since we never really have to multiply numbers greater than 27.

Comment: Use the fact that 2 and 27 are coprime, so in some cases you can just divide the congruence.

Comment: $2^\alpha-1$ should be multiple of $3$, so $\alpha$ is even. Then we know that $2^\beta(2^\alpha-1)-3$ is multiple of $9$, so we can reduce the number of cases for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ modulo $6$. And we can do again for the original equality, though it will be complex to do by hand..